# Specifying a source in puppet

Tags: puppet

I am writing a puppet manifest on puppet master to monitor a folder with a list of files on a agent.

I do not know how do i specify a remote value for the "source" attribute of my file resource type, since the folder is located on agent and i do not want to copy the folder with its content on my master since that would unnessaryly utillize some space.

```
file { '/XYZ/ybc/WebSphere85dev/AppServer/properties':
ensure  => directory,
owner   => wsuser,
group   => webapp,
source  => "??????",
recurse => true,
show_diff => true,
```

What value should i specify for source?

Answer (score 1):

If you specify a `source`, the `file` resource that you have created will be synced with the `source` (it can be in the master, or in the agent node), and the diffs will be present in the puppet report (it's the default, you don't need the `show_diff` attribute). If you don't specify a `source` attribute you won't get the diffs you are expecting, since there is nothing to compare with.

If you only want to be warned about changes in that directory you can use the `audit` attribute. However, you won't get the diffs that you are expecting, just a message saying that the contents have changed (again, there's nothing to compare):

```
file {
    '/XYZ/ybc/WebSphere85dev/AppServer/properties':
        ensure    => directory,
        audit     => content,
        recurse   => true,
        show_diff => true,
}
```

You can specify `all`, any attribute or array of attributes to be audited:  http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/metaparameter.html#audit

Also, bear in mind that with the manifest that you posted you are changing the `owner` and `group` of the directory `/XYZ/ybc/WebSphere85dev/AppServer/properties` and its contents.